# Inserting values to a form with relationship in laravel (Referring projectid)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

There is a a single form which takes in details and save it to 4 different tables in db. Project, Events, Donation and Opportunities. Project has many Events, many Donation and many Opportunities. I want to use the project id in other tables as well. but when I save the Form the details are stored in each 4 tables but the project is not been taken for the other 3 tables Events, Donation and Opportunity. Its value is 0. How to take that particular project id(auto-increment) in all other three tables.

My ProjectController is like this:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
public function getProject()
{
    return view ('other.project');
}

public function postProject(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'ptitle' => 'required|max:200',
        'pdescription' => 'required',
        'etitle' => 'required|max:200',
        'edetails' => 'required',
        'dtotal' => 'required',
        'oposition' => 'required|max:100',
        'odescription' => 'required',
    ]);

    Project::create([
        'ptitle' => $request->input('ptitle'),
        'pdescription' => $request->input('pdescription'),
        'pduration' => $request->input('pduration'),
        'psdate' => $request->input('psdate'),
        'pedate' => $request->input('pedate'),
        'pcategory' => $request->input('pcategory'),
        'pimage' => $request->input('pimage'),
    ]);

    Event::create([ 
        'pro_id' => $request->input('pid'),
        'etitle' => $request->input('etitle'),
        'pdetails' => $request->input('pdetails'),
        'edate' => $request->input('edate'),
        'etime' => $request->input('etime'),
        'elocation' => $request->input('elocation'),
        'eimage' => $request->input('eimage'),
    ]);

    Donation::create([  
        'pro_id' => $request->input('pid'),         
        'dtotal' => $request->input('dtotal'),
        'dinhand' => $request->input('dinhand'),
        'dbankaccount' => $request->input('dbankaccount'),
    ]);

    Opportunity::create([
        'pro_id' => $request->input('pid'), 
        'oposition' => $request->input('oposition'),
        'odescription' => $request->input('odescription'),
        'olocation' => $request->input('olocation'),
        'odeadline' => $request->input('odeadline'),
    ]);

 return redirect()
        ->route('home')
        ->with('info', 'Your project has been created.');
}
```

My Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'ptitle',
    'pdescription',
    'pduration',
    'psdate',
    'pedate',  
    'pcategory', 
    'pimage',
];

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ngovol\Models\Event', 'pro_id');
}

public function donations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ngovol\Models\Donation', 'pro_id');
}

public function opportunities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ngovol\Models\Event', 'pro_id');
}

protected $hidden = [

];
}
```

Event Model:

```
class Event extends Model
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'events';

protected $fillable = [
    'pro_id',
    'etitle',
    'edetails',
    'edate',
    'etime',
    'elocation',
    'eimage',
];

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ngovol\Models\Project', 'pro_id'); 
}
}
```

Donation Model:

```
class Donation extends Model
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'pro_id',
    'dtotal',
    'dinhand',
    'drequired',
    'dbankaccount',
];

protected $hidden = [

];

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ngovol\Models\Project', 'pro_id');
}
}
```

Opportunity Model:

```
class Opportunity extends Model
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'pro_id',
    'oposition',
    'odescription',
    'olocation',
    'odeadline',

];

protected $hidden = [

];

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ngovol\Models\Project', 'pro_id');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better try following code

```
$project = Project::create( $request->only(['ptitle', 'pdescription', 'pduration', 'psdate', 'pedate', 'pcategory', 'pimage']));

$project->events()->create( $request->only(['etitle', 'pdetails', 'edate', 'etime', 'elocation', 'eimage']));

$project->donations()->create($request->only(['dtotal', 'dinhand', 'dbankaccount']));

$project->opportunities()->create($request->only(['oposition','odescription','olocation','odeadline']));
```

Comment: Thanks. But i got a error when i tried it. "BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::event()"   This error. Sorry im new to laravel.

Comment: Thanks the table is referring the project id. But a new problem has incurred now. Only donation table is taking in values. Event table is inserting 2 rows with event id & pro_id but other values are null. And the opportunity table is null.No row is inserted. Please help me

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG=true`  in your .env file to find detailed error.

Comment: Its working perfectly. Found the error. Thanks @Praveen Tamil